# Do apps made with Electron need to be installed?

Tags: electron, chromium

Do Electron apps need to be installed on Windows / Mac?

Comment: If I could, I'd roll back to the first version and do some light editing. I believe the question comes across better in one of its former states than in the current minimalistic form.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're familiar with Electron's docs on [distribution](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution) and that you have packaged your app in some way.

In that case *installing* is just a fancy term for copying the required files to a possibly specifiable location and maybe some "infrastructure" tasks such as creating links on the desktop etc.

In other words: after packaging, you can just run your app.